# Cannot get expected result in using Excel VBA SUMIF

Tags: excel, vba

I have a trouble when I try to write a For loop to assign each of the row have a cell that has a formula `SUMIF`

```
For r = 2 To counter5 - 1
    temp_str = "B" + CStr(r)
    Sheets("Result").Cells(r, 18).Offset = _
       WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("B2:B5000"), """*" & temp_str & "*""", _
       Range("I2:I5000"))
Next
```

---

Which counter5 stores the final row number of my "Result" worksheet, after I run the code, I have only got the 0 in the cells of the column R, what mistake I have made to cause I cannot get the expected result, I have also try to change the "Offset" method to "Formula" instead but still got the same result.

Comment: Placed * wrongly in the double quotes.  Place it in the middle like this ""*"".  on both the places (Before and after the variable).

Comment: This: `"""*" & temp_str & "*"""` should just be: `"*" & temp_str & "*"`

Comment: I have tried to change the quotes, but the result still the same. Anything related to configuration may affect?

Comment: Do you want to do SUMIF with the criteria being the value of cell B2? Because now you'r criteria is *B2*.

Comment: Yes, criteria is B2, I am finally give up with the WorksheetFunction.SumIf and use formular1c1 to type the string and got success, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

For WorksheetFunction.SumIf, the following will work (with you current code, you are searching for the string "B2", for example, where I imagine you want the value in the cell?):

```
For r = 2 To counter5 - 1
    Sheets("Result").Cells(r, 18).Offset = _
        WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("B2:B5000"), "*" & Cells(r, 2) & "*", _
        Range("I2:I5000"))
Next
```